# Effect of total pressure on the component condensation in a gas mixture

Tags: pressure, gas, condensation

Suppose we take two gases in a vessel with a movable piston. We compress the mixture until first drop of condensate appears. Suppose temperature remains constant during compression. Therefore when you compress, pressure increases. Condensate will form at a given temperature, **when partial pressure of a gas becomes equal to its saturation pressure** at that temperature. This is what I have understood from explanations about partial pressure, saturation pressure, gas mixture condensation etc.

I also understand that the temperature and molecular repulsion tend to separate the molecules while pressure and molecular attraction tend to confine the molecules. The molecules in the liquid phase are more confined than in the vapour phase. When any substance exists in the liquid phase at certain pressure, it means that this pressure is sufficient to confine the molecules together to form a liquid. For the liquid to boil, the molecules should possess enough energy to overcome this pressure. When the energy is supplied as heat, the molecular repulsion increases so that the molecules are able to overcome the pressure which is holding the molecules together. Hence the molecular confinement can be broken only when the vapour pressure becomes equal to or greater than the pressure applied on the liquid.

Now, my question is, in the first paragraph it says “Condensate will form at a given temperature, when partial pressure of a gas becomes equal to its saturation pressure at that temperature”. But from the second paragraph, it seems like the total pressure in the vessel has a role in confining the molecules in the liquid phase. So when we say,  “Condensate will form at a given temperature, when partial pressure of a gas becomes equal to its saturation pressure at that temperature”, what exactly is the role of the pressure exerted by the second component gas on the condensation of first component gas? If condensation of first gas is only governed by its partial pressure and its saturation pressure, does not the total pressure have any role in confining the first component gas in its liquid form?

Comment: Saturation pressure is when the vapor pressure of your gas/fluid is equal to the total pressure of the gases, That's where your other gas component comes into play. You could consider this backwards, for what pressure at constant temperature does your fluid just begin to boil away.

Comment: @R. Rankin Thank you for your comment but could you please elaborate a bit more?